# Show that if $x$ is an accumulation point of an ultrafilter on $X$, then the neighborhood filter is contained in the filter

Tags: general-topology, filters

> Show that if $x$ is an accumulation point of an ultrafilter $\mathcal{F}$ on $X$,
>   then the neighborhood filter $\mathcal{F}_x$ is contained in the filter i.e. $\mathcal{F}_x \subseteq \mathcal{F}$

Definitions:

1. $\mathcal{F}_x = \{U \text{ open} , x \in U\}$ is a neighborhood filter
2. $x$ is an accumulation point of $\mathcal{F}$  on $X$ if for every element $F \in \mathcal{F}$, and every $U \in \mathcal{F}_x$, $F \cap U \neq \varnothing$
3. $\mathcal{F}$ is an ultrafilter if for all $F$ a filter on $X$, $\mathcal{F} \not\subset F$

I'm close but stuck

Let $x$ be an accumulation point of an ultrafilter $\mathcal{F}$. Then we wish to show that for all $U \in \mathcal{F}_X, U \in \mathcal{F}$, so that $\mathcal{F}_x \subseteq \mathcal{F}$

Since $x$ is an accumulation point, then for all $F \in \mathcal{F}$, $U \cap F \neq \varnothing$

It is not clear how I should proceed to show that $U \in \mathcal{F}$ from this point, can someone offer divine assistance?

Comment: You're not having problems *writing* the proof. You're having problems *coming up* with the proof. So I removed the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well. $\cal F$ is an **ultrafilter**. Which is equivalent to saying that for every $A\subseteq X$ *exactly* one of the two holds, $A\in\cal F$ or $X\setminus A\in\cal F$.

Using the fact that $x$ is an accumulation point, there can be only one possible answer for any open set $U$ with $x\in U$.

Comment: Sorry I am not seeing why $X\backslash U \notin \mathcal{F}$

Comment: Use the definition of an accumulation point.